# Replace a character in different elements with the same class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split, classname

I have several paragraphs in my page. They all have the same class name. I want to replace a character that is in all of them. I tried something like this:

```
  var str = $(".foo").html;
  var res = str.split("　").join("");
  $(".foo").html = res;
```

But I get the error: `TypeError: str.split is not a function`

I noticed that if I target a single paragraph, with its unique Id, everything works fine. I just cannot do it with several paragraphs at the same time, using their class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".foo")` returns a list, therefore, you should iterate over each paragraph and change its content. You can use the [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function as follows:

```js
$( ".foo" ).each(function( index, element ) {
     $(element).html( $(element).html().split(" ").join("") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="foo">hello world</p>
<p class="foo">hello world</p>
<p class="foo">hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [each function](https://api.jquery.com/each/)